# Is there a way to have a typewriter effect for the titlebar C#

Tags: c#

Like I want the titlebar to have this type of typewriter effect where each letter comes after a two second delay..

```
H e l l o P r o g r a m
```

with a two second delay

```
  private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "H";
            timer2.Stop();
            this.Text = "He";

        }
```

I've tried this..

Comment: @stuartd no , is it possible or not ?

Comment: @CyraX6 You should provide us with the error/problem you're having - not simply saying it doesn't work. As far as I can see, you may be getting a cross-thread exception, nothing happens at all, the UI freezes, or only the full text is displayed. That's 4 possibilities already.

Comment: It's a simple question and it's obvious his code won't work as expected even without cross threading exception etc and that the OP is primarily asking for the logic for displaying as required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track

```
using System.Windows.Threading; //add reference to WindowsBase.  this gives you access to the DispatcherTimer
DispatcherTimer timer { get; set; } //i used this because it runs on the UI thread which allows it to update.
int letterCount { get; set; }  //i used this to keep track of how many loops ran
string message { get; set; } // set the message you want to display

public Form1()
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Text = ""; //clear the text.  this can be done in the designer
    letterCount = 0; // set the count to 0
    timer = new DispatcherTimer(); //configure the timer
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    message = "Hello World!"; //set the message
    timer.Start(); //start the timer
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text += message[letterCount]; // add the letter to the title bar
    letterCount++; // increment the count
    if (letterCount > message.Length -1) // stop the timer once the message finishes to avoid getting an error
    {
        timer.Stop(); // use this to stop after once

        // use this to clear and restart
        letterCount = 0;
        this.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't even know about dispatcher timer

Comment: When it finished writing all the letters it gives error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in AKP 1.exe

Comment: did you include the last part?  you need to stop the timer once all the letters in the message have been used.

Comment: okay yeah  i put it under another timer tick sorry. it works great thanks

Comment: how would i make this clear all title after it fully writes then write again then clear again and write again (infinite loop)? thankss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112096/discussion-between-cyrax6-and-david-greilach).