# text in c# like poke games

Tags: c#, text, scroll

I'm wondering if you can make c# text have a slight delay between each letter like old games example pokemon. Video example to show exactly what I mean (look at the textbox) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTyt2e90Nu4

I thought it looked weird when the text just appeared directly. I tried doing

```
Console.Write("something"); 
Thread.Sleep(200); 
Console.Write("something else");
```

But it didn't turn out good.

Comment: Why didn't your approach work out?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing one character at a time in a C# Console Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718901/writing-one-character-at-a-time-in-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: @VincentGarbrant You say your solution didn't turn out well. Can you explain why your solution was inadequate?

Comment: Btw what you're looking for is often called "typewriter effect", you'll find several questions on that topic here on SO to get some inspiration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have a typewriter effect for the titlebar C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265080/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-typewriter-effect-for-the-titlebar-c-sharp)

Comment: I have tried the writing one letter at a time thing but for long sentences it's really time consuming if I would just write "Hi how are you as an example:

Comment: Console.Write("H"); Thread.Sleep(100); Console.Write("i"); Thread.Sleep(100); Console.Write(" h"); Thread.Sleep(100); Console.Write("o"); Thread.Sleep(100); Console.Write("w");

Comment: I have tried typewriter but I didnt get it to work, I didn't understand most of the tutorial. any one can explain the procces of it and how to write lines with it?

Comment: As you're probably aware, 1000 = 1 second. You say for long sentences it becomes too long. Do you want the length of the input string to be part of the function? If so, then calculate how long you sleep it. If I decided that I wanted it to complete at or around 5 seconds (rounding could pose issues), that'd be 5000 total. If I were doing the word "water", that's 5 characters. 5000 / 5 = 1000 so each character would sleep for 1 second (5 characters, 5 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        DelayWrite("It's dangerous to go alone!");
        DelayWrite("Take this.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DelayWrite(string text, int charDelay = 50, bool delayNewLine = true) {
        foreach (char c in text) {
            Console.Write(c);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(charDelay);
        }            
        if (delayNewLine) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

You can then customize the speed of the printout by adding a second parameter to the DelayWrite() function, such as

`DelayWrite("It's dangerous to go alone!", 10);` for faster, or

`DelayWrite("It's dangerous to go alone!", 1000);` for slower speed.

Comment: Thank you very much this is great. But if I want to make multiple/more text lines do I need to copy the whole script again (that you sent) and edit the text

Comment: From what it looks like, Daniel's solution will complete the first line and then move down to the next line. Judging by the video, the logic he gave should match (though I've personally never attempted anything like that in the console).

Comment: Which video do you mean? @robert

Comment: the Pokemon one